# GITLAB (Freely Gitlab hosted) Contributor vs User

Tags: git, gitlab

On Gitlab ([Freely hosted by GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-com/)) [Gitlab Products](https://about.gitlab.com/products/)

What is the difference between a collaborators  and a user (as for [Community edition](https://about.gitlab.com/products/#compare-options)?)

I simply want to create private repositories to work with 3-4 other peoples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the glossary

[User](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/university/glossary/README.html#user)

> Anyone interacting with the software.

[Collaborator](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/university/glossary/README.html#collaborator)

> Person with read and write access to a repository who has been invited by repository owner.

Refer the [permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/permissions.html) page, to find out how to add permissions for a user.

Also refer the [add user to project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/add-user/add-user.html), to add a user to a project and make them a collaborator

[GitLab.com](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-com/) will provide unlimited public & private repositories & unlimited users/collaborators for [free](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-com/#why-gitlab-com-will-be-free-forever) with some restrictions on space, build time.

> In the future we might also charge for the following things:
>
> - Build artifact storage above a certain size (currently unlimited even    with a free account)
> - Container images storage above a certain size    (currently unlimited even with a free account)
> - GitLab Pages with very    high traffic (currently unlimited even with a free acount)
> - Restrict    the build minutes in the bronze plan (move unlimited minutes to the    silver account)
> - Windows & MacOS Runners for GitLab CI (not available    now but you can always bring your own Runner)